# NgUpload additional parameter

Tags: file-upload, angularjs

---

I am using [NgUpload](https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload) to upload images.
The functionality is working perfect and I have a callback function `uploadSubmit`

```
$scope.uploadSubmit = (content,completed) ->
            if completed
                $scope.images.push JSON.parse(content)
```

I need to pass additional parameter other than content,completed.any way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to pass it in since the uploadSubmit is already in scope and you should be able to access any model defined in scope.

```
$scope.uploadSubmit = function(content,completed){
    var value = $scope.otherModel;
}
```